# Docker curl to other container in same host

Tags: docker

I have 2 containers, first one running on port 80 and the other is running on port 8022, I try to make a curl request from the container that`s is running on port 8022 to the container on port 80 and i get a empty response.

For the container on port 8022 i run this command:

```
docker run -d -it --privileged -p 0.0.0.0:8022:80 -v ~/path/to/my/app:/var/www/app --network=bridge --memory 1073741824  my/app:latest
```

If a make a curl request to other host form example google, I get the response correctly.

Thanks for help

**UPDATED**
Ok I can solve this, creating a network and using this network in both containers, then I add to host file of the 8022 container the IP of the port 80 container.

Thanks for @zero298 for help!!

Comment: If you use a user-defined network and name your containers, you shouldn't need to use a host file.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simple example of how to do inter-container communication over a user-defined, bridged network.  Here are the 3 files that I have defined to make this possible:

### `~/Desktop/code/bootstrap.sh`

This will kick off the demo by first creating a user defined, isolated network that your containers can talk over named `example_nw`.  It then creates a new container, named "servertest", that will hold the server we will `curl` to.  I'm using a `node` container because I'm just more familiar with it.

It will also create a volume that binds to your machines `~/Desktop/code/` directory which should contain all the code that we are using, including the node `server.js` script.  The server listens on port 3000 and responds with: "Hello World`".

After creating the server, it kicks off another container, named "curler" that will install curl (debian doesn't come with it installed).  After that, it curls to `servertest:3000` and gets the correct reply because they are both connected to the same docker, user-defined, network: `example_nw`.

After completing, it cleans up by killing the server container and removing the `example_nw` network.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create user-defined network
docker network create example_nw

# Create server to listen to pings on our network
docker run \
--rm \
-d \
-v ~/Desktop/code:/my/stuff \
--name servertest \
--expose 3000 \
--network example_nw \
node node /my/stuff/server

# Create a curler
docker run \
-it \
--rm \
-v ~/Desktop/code:/my/stuff \
--name pingtest \
--network example_nw debian \
/my/stuff/curler.sh

# Clean up
docker container stop servertest
docker network rm example_nw
```

### `~/Desktop/code/server.js`

This is a really simple node.js script that will create a server that listens on port 3000.

```js
/*jslint node:true, esversion:6*/

"use strict";

const http = require("http"),
    port = 3000;

// Make a server
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Got request");
    res.end("Hello World!\n");
});

// Have the server listen
server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

### `~/Desktop/code/curler.sh`

This just installs curl in the container and then curls to `servertest:3000`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt update
apt install -y curl
curl servertest:3000
```

Running `~/Desktop/code/bootstrap.sh` will demonstrate the communication.

---

I would recommend reading the Docker documentation: [Work with network commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) because it gives a lot of good examples and use cases.

Comment: @Algoleigol Not without more information.  Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response , i tried this and dont works, do you knoe where could be the problem : #!/usr/bin/env bash # Create user-defined network docker network create example_nw # Create server to listen to pings on our network docker run --rm -d -it --privileged -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v ~/Sites/api:/var/www/api --name api --memory 1073741824 --network example_nw alogleigol/api:nginx # Create a curler docker run --rm -d -it --privileged -p 8022:80 -v ~/Sites/app_example:/var/www/app_example --name app_test --network example_nw alogleigol/app_example:latest

Comment: I get curl: (7) Failed to connect to app.local port 80: Connection refused

Comment: you're connecting to app.local but the name of the container is api, so try to execute curl http://api

Answer (score 3):

Your container is not listening on port 8022, you've pushed the port 8022 to forward to the container's port 80. From container to container, you connect to the container port, not the published port on the host. So remove 8022 from your curl command to go to the default port 80.

---

For container to container networking, you need the containers to be on a common docker network. And for docker's internal DNS, you need to be on a docker network other than the default bridge network named "bridge" (that "bridge" network has some historical properties that does not have DNS enabled). You can `docker network create $network_name` and then run your containers with the `--net $network_name` option to implement this.

You do not need to modify the host files or use the deprecated "link" functionality for container to container networking.

Comment: I missed the part about "empty response". What response are you expecting? Is your application generating the expected response? If not, this is an application issue, not a problem with docker or curl.

Comment: if access to the container running on port 8022, docker exec -it 3213123213 bash, and then i run curl http:app.local i get a empty response, but if i run curl google.com i get correct response

Answer (score 2):

This is an example to use the user-generated network

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run --network=mynetwork -d -p 127.0.0.1:8022:80 --name mynginx nginx
docker run -it --network=mynetwork appropriate/curl http://mynginx
```

Otherwise you can use the older --link option

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8022:80 --name mynginx nginx
docker run -it --link=nginx appropriate/curl http://mynginx
```

Answer (score -2):

Use ngrok.
Let's say we have localhost:8010 and localhost:8020.
With ngrok, forward locahost:8020 to xxx-000-000-000-00.ngrok-free.app. And then localhost:8010 can reach xxx-000-000-000-00.ngrok-free.app

Comment: Hi, why ngrok? Docker has already the capabilities the author is looking for